# Wave equation of a TL from the Lagrangian description

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, electric-circuits, field-theory, variational-calculus

For an infinite transmission line between x = 0 and x = d, the Lagrangian (in terms of flux density $ \phi $ is:

$$ L = \int dx \{ \frac{c}{2}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t})^2 -  \frac{1}{2l}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})^2 \} $$

I need to show that the "equation of motion" of this lagrangian is the wave equation of the TL:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} = lc \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} $$

I'm aware that I need to use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find that out, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to solve for $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} $. I caught that $ \dot{\phi} $ is $ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} $ since the "$x$-axis" isn't time dependent, so I got the $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} $ term figured out, but I'm not able to get the 2nd $x$-derivative from $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} $.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\phi$ depends on t and x. The term $\cfrac{d}{dt}\cfrac{dL}{d\dot{q}}  \rightarrow \partial_{\mu}\cfrac{\partial L }{\partial(\partial_{μ}\phi)}$ where $\mu=t,x$ in Euler-Lagrange equations will yield the two terms you want.